# Не появляется яблоко для змеи. PyGame. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Здравсвуйте, есть код:

```
import pygame
import random

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption('Змейка')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 250
y = 250

appleWidth = 10
appleHeight = 10

width = 7
height = 7
speed = 7

direction = "right"

parts = []
apple = {}
snake = ''
isApple = False

def drawWindow():
    part = []
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    snake = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    part.append(snake)
    part.append(x)
    part.append(y)
    parts.append(part)
    pygame.display.update()

def move():
    global x, y

    if direction == 'right':
        x += speed
    elif direction == 'left':
        x -= speed
    elif direction == 'up':
        y -= speed
    elif direction == 'down':
        y += speed

    if x < 0:
        x = 500
    elif x > 500:
        x = 0
    if y < 0:
        y = 500
    elif y > 500:
        y = 0

def create_apple():
    global isApple 
    global apple

    xApple = random.randint(0, 500)
    yApple = random.randint(0, 500)
    for part in parts:
        if parts[part][1] == x and parts[part][2] == y:
            create_apple()
            break

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xApple, yApple, appleWidth, appleHeight))
    isApple = True
    apple['x'] = x
    apple['y'] = y

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if isApple == False:
        create_apple()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    move()

    if direction == 'right' or direction == 'left':
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            direction = "up"
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            direction = "down"
    else:
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            direction = "left"
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            direction = "right"


    drawWindow()
```

Суть в чём: это мои попытки создать змейку. Я пытаюсь создать через функцию create_apple() яблоко для змеи. Запускаю код, а яблоко не появляется. В чём может быть проблема? Как её можно решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде была не одна ошибка, поэтому я просто переписал основные моменты:

```
import pygame
import random

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption('Змейка')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 250
y = 250

appleWidth = 10
appleHeight = 10

xApple = 0
yApple = 0

width = 7
height = 7
speed = 7

direction = "right"

parts = []
apple = {}
snake = ''
isApple = False

def drawWindow():
    try:
        a = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (parts[-1][1], parts[-1][2], width, height))
    except:
        pass

    part = []
    snake = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    part.append(snake)
    part.append(x)
    part.append(y)
    parts.append(part)
    pygame.display.update()

def move():
    global x, y

    if direction == 'right':
        x += speed
    elif direction == 'left':
        x -= speed
    elif direction == 'up':
        y -= speed
    elif direction == 'down':
        y += speed

    if x < 0:
        x = 500
    elif x > 500:
        x = 0
    if y < 0:
        y = 500
    elif y > 500:
        y = 0

def create_apple():
    global isApple, apple, win, xApple, yApple

    xApple = random.randint(0, 500)
    yApple = random.randint(0, 500)

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (xApple, yApple, appleWidth, appleHeight))
    isApple = True
    apple['x'] = xApple
    apple['y'] = yApple

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if isApple == False:
        create_apple()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    move()

    if direction == 'right' or direction == 'left':
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            direction = "up"
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            direction = "down"
    else:
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            direction = "left"
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            direction = "right"


    drawWindow()
    if abs(xApple - parts[-1][1]) < 7 and abs(yApple - parts[-1][2]) < 7:
        create_apple()
```

Начнем с камня преткновения, это строчка `win.fill((0, 0, 0))`. Данная функция зачищала экран перед каждым движением змейки, яблоко исчезало соответственно. Чтобы это исправить, я изменил её на другую функцию, которая вместо полной зачистки рисует предыдущий фрейм змейки, но уже черного цвета(функция обрамлена в try, так как при первом обращении к массиву возникает ошибка, предыдущий фрейм еще не существует)

Второе, теперь координаты яблока - глобальные переменные, это нужно для того, чтобы проверка на поедание яблока шла непрерывно в теле `while run:`, а не в самой функции создания яблока. Сама проверка смотрит, находится ли змейка в круге с радиусом 7 от яблока и если это так, то создается новое яблоко. Функцию удаления фрейма старого яблока я оставил на вас, благо она мало отличается от змеиной.

В остальном не вижу особых проблем(кроме неаккуратного использования похожих переменных x & xApple, тк вы в них и запутались)

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Результат тот же. Красная бегающая точка без яблок.

Comment: @DiHASTRO, ответ изменен

Comment: Премного благодарен!